# Change part of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, pattern-matching

I'm starting in Mathematica. I would like your help to solve the following question (which is really basic):

Whenever the sequence 1, 2, 1 appears in a given list, I want to change this part of the list to the sequence 2, 1, 2.

For example, given the list lis1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, **1, 2, 1**}, I want to get the list lis2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, **2, 1, 2**}.

Yes, for example my list is lis3 = {1,2,3,4,3, **1,2,1**, 3,2}. I want to get the list lis4 = {1,2,3,4,3, **2,1,2**, 3,2}

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you want the result to be if the input list is {1,2,1,2,1}? Make sure the implementation you choose does the desired thing on examples like this.

Answer (score 14):

Try [`SequenceReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceReplace.html)

```
SequenceReplace[{1, 2, 1} -> Sequence[2, 1, 2]] @ lis1
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2}

```
SequenceReplace[{1, 2, 1} -> Sequence[2, 1, 2]] @ lis3
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2}

***Alternative methods:***

[`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html) + [`SequencePosition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequencePosition.html):

```
MapAt[3 - # &, #, Span @@@ SequencePosition[#, {1, 2, 1}]] &@lis1
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2}

```
MapAt[3 - # &, #, Span @@@ SequencePosition[#, {1, 2, 1}]] &@lis3
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2}

[`SubsetMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubsetMap.html) + [`SequencePosition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequencePosition.html) + [`Fold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html):

```
Fold[SubsetMap[3 - # &, ##] &][#, Span @@@ SequencePosition[#, {1, 2, 1}]] &@lis1
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2}

```
Fold[SubsetMap[3 - # &, ##] &][#, Span @@@ SequencePosition[#, {1, 2, 1}]] &@lis3
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2}

[`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) assignment:

```
Module[{l = #},
  Do[l[[i]] = {2, 1, 2}, {i, Span @@@ SequencePosition[#, {1, 2, 1}]}]; l]&@lis1
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2}

```
Module[{l = #}, 
 Do[l[[i]] = {2, 1, 2}, {i, Span @@@ SequencePosition[#, {1, 2, 1}]}]; l] &@lis3
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2}

Answer (score 10):

[Patterns](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Patterns.html) also work.

```
list = {1, 3, 5, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2} /. {a___, 1, 2, 1, b___} -> {a, 2, 1, 2, b}
```

gives:

> {1, 3, 5, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2}

Comment: What kind of patterns? What is the explanation for why this solution works?